# Resolving Button Overlapping

Tags: html, css

I made some buttons, but they keep overlapping on the bottom half with the other buttons.

I have tried fixing this by modifying the opacity, and other things, however it only made it look worse and showed both buttons on top of each other. Here is the code I have so far so you can see the issue.

https://codepen.io/Test-t-the-builder/pen/dyaWQpe

````css
.title {
  margin-top: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.second {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14vw;
  margin-top: 8vw;
  height: auto;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.899);
  text-shadow: 0.29vw 0.29vw 0.29vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 900;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0.06vw;
  width: 30vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 7vw;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  box-shadow: 0.298vw 0.298vw 0.298vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bottom {
  border-radius: 0 0 2vw 2vw;
}

.top {
  border-radius: 2vw 2vw 0 0;
}

.center:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.top:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.bottom:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: -3vw;
}

#fadein {
  animation: fadein 1500ms;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.first {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 9.5vw;
  margin-bottom: -1.19vw;
  margin-top: 4.5%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.899);
  text-shadow: 0.29vw 0.29vw 0.29vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee8e52, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab, rgb(255, 0, 255)), lightcoral;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50%;
  }
}

* {
  cursor: cell;
}

```
````

```html
<div id="fadein">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="first">World</p>
    <p class="second">News</p>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="about.html" class="button top">About</a>
      <a href="breakingnews.html" class="button center">Breaking News</a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="button center">Contact</a>
      <a href="Q&A.html" class="button bottom">Q&A</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```