# Buttons making very weird animation on my website

Tags: html, css

The problem is that after I added z-index to my css, a weird animation happens when you hover over my buttons. It looks like it is overlapping, and then not overlapping.

I tried changing the z-index values, but it just makes the animation stranger. I have attached an example of the issue and the weird animation it is creating.

https://codepen.io/Test-t-the-builder/pen/dyaWwrY

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 6vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.second {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14vw;
  margin-top: 8vw;
  height: auto;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.899);
  text-shadow: 0.29vw 0.29vw 0.29vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 900;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0.06vw;
  width: 30vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 7vw;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  box-shadow: 0.298vw 0.298vw 0.298vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
  backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.bottom {
  border-radius: 0 0 2vw 2vw;
}

.top {
  border-radius: 2vw 2vw 0 0;
}

.center:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.top:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.bottom:hover {
  border-radius: 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw 2.381vw;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: -3vw;
}

#fadein {
  animation: fadein 1500ms;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.first {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 9.5vw;
  margin-bottom: -1.19vw;
  margin-top: 4.5%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.899);
  text-shadow: 0.29vw 0.29vw 0.29vw rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee8e52, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab, rgb(255, 0, 255)), lightcoral;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50%;
  }
}

* {
  cursor: cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadein">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="first">World</p>
    <p class="second">News</p>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="about.html" class="button top">About</a>
      <a href="breakingnews.html" class="button center">Breaking News</a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="button center">Contact</a>
      <a href="Q&A.html" class="button bottom">Q&A</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How's this question different from [your last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461447/resolving-button-overlapping)?